# Don't apply CSS transition from focus to blur

Tags: css, transition

Apologies if this question has been asked; I tried a lot of different wording trying to find an answer but to no avail!

Basically I'm using CSS transitions on my inputs (only for `border-color`).

When hover over or hover out, I want the transition to be applied.
When focusing and unfocusing, I want the CSS to be instant (i.e. no transition duration).

So far, I have the hovers working fine, the blur to focus is instant, but the focus to blur is taking the transition property.

My code at the moment is as follows:

```
input{
  border:1px solid #444444;
  transition:border-color 1s;
}
input:hover{ border-color:#666666; transition:border-color 1s; }
input:focus{ border-color:#D26D22; transition:none; }`
```

I know I could easily do this with JQuery, but I'd like a CSS solution if it's possible, thanks.

Edit: Fiddle showing this here https://jsfiddle.net/xamy95uv/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input:not(:focus){transition:none}`